# Pry in Rails (4) -- why doesn't a simple IRB=Pry work 100%?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pry

So I like Pry. One day, I found this hack on how to get it instead of `irb` in `rails console`:

First, put it in the **Gemfile**:

```
gem 'pry', group: :development
```

then,

- `require` it
- unless `require` fails, make the IRB constant point to the contents of the Pry constant, and silence the warning that constants shouldn't be changed

In code:

```
#In the configure block in config/environments/development.rb
silence_warnings do
  begin
    require 'pry'
    IRB=Pry
  rescue LoadError
  end
end
```

The problem is, this results in a rails console with a few blemishes such as the `reload!` or `helper` not working.

Fortunately, there's a `pry-rails` gem, but I'm wondering, why do I need it and why doesn't the straightforward, simplistic approach work 100%?